# why my junit test fail at this code?

Tags: java, junit

```
public String replaceVowels(String s){
   String replacement = "";
   for(int i = 0; i <s.length(); i++){
       if(s.charAt(i)=='a' || s.charAt(i)=='A' ||
               s.charAt(i)=='e' || s.charAt(i)=='E'||
               s.charAt(i)=='i' || s.charAt(i)=='I'||
               s.charAt(i)=='o' || s.charAt(i)=='O'||
               s.charAt(i)=='u' || s.charAt(i)=='U'){
           replacement = replacement + '*';
         }else{
             replacement = replacement + s.charAt(i);
         }

   }
   return replacement;
```

}

I want the code to replace vowels by * in the string and here is my test code

```
@Test public void tests8(){
code.Solution s =  new code.Solution();
String input = "book ";
String expected = "b**k";
String actual = s.replaceVowels(input);
assertTrue("Expected was" +expected+"but the actual was" +actual  ,  expected == actual);
```

}

The error is so weird when I run the junit it said that

expected was b * * k but the actual was b * * k

Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: You have a space at the end. So replaceVowels returns `"b**k "` but you expected `"b**k"`.

Comment: Voting to close this as a simple typographical error.

Comment: Even if the space is removed, you will need to use [`expected.equals(actual)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) (or just use `assertEquals` instead).

Answer (score 0):

You should use `assertEquals(String, Object, Object)`, since you need to compare the values of the two strings, not their identity.

(And you probably don't need your custom message any more if you do)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the trailing space in `"b**k "` and also use the `string.equals(String other)` function to compare strings, not the `==` operator. `==` will only work when comparing string literals because they will point to the same object.

Comment: So for example, if I changed this method  s.charAt(i)=='a'. The result would be s.chatAt(i).equals(a)? Is that right?

Comment: Yes, since a char is basically a number, you can compare them using either way

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the typo @immibis mentions,  your testcase reads:
`assertTrue("Expected was" +expected+"but the actual was" +actual  ,  expected == actual);`

It should read:
`assertTrue("Expected was" +expected+"but the actual was" +actual  ,  expected.equals(actual));`

`==` is not the same as `.equals(I)`.

`==` means are they the same instance, whereas `.equals()` means they have the same content.

Comment: Use ` for code formatting, not {}